# Batch - Read file and search for token

Tags: batch-file

i have a textfile with different values in it.

```
define Domain "http://xyz.co"
define Remote "https:/www.test.co"
define OUTFILE "Folder name"
...
```

I would like to read the file and search for special tokens like Domain oder **OUTFILE** and set the value from the double quotes to a variable. The value inside the double quotes can contain spaces.

```
for /F "eol=; tokens=*" %%z in ("filename.txt") do (
set value=%%z
ECHO %%z | FINDSTR /C:"Domain" >nul & IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (GOTO ITERATE)
)

:ITERATE
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^=^" %%p in ("%value%") do set Domain=%%p


echo %Domain%
```

This works so far for one value.

Is it possible to parse only once the file?
Is there a better way to get the content inside the double quotes?

Thanks!

Comment: `for /F "usebackq tokens=2*" %%a in ("filename.txt") do set "%%a=%%~b"` After that, you have _all tokens_ in same-named variables. For example: `echo %OUTFILE%`

Answer (score 1):

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\01\SO_53101679.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

::clear env vars
For %%A in (Domain OUTFILE) do set "%%A="

for /F "eol=; tokens=1,2*" %%A in ('
  findstr /i "^define.Domain ^define.OUTFILE" filename.txt
') do Set %%B=%%C

For %%A in (Domain OUTFILE) do if defined %%A Echo %%A=!%%~A!
```

Sample output based on your above fragment:

```
> Q:\Test\2018\11\01\SO_53101679.cmd
Domain=http://xyz.co
OUTFILE=Folder name
```